# I cannot get the full physicial path of a selected file

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload

I want full path of selected file using GWT by using FileUpload. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it. Imagine that I am the client and you are the server. I give you the full file path "C:/My Documents/passwords.txt", how would you as being the server ever programmatically access the content of the file? With `new File("C:/My Documents/passwords.txt")` maybe? No, think logically about it, this ain't going to work as we both runs at *physically different machines*. The information about the full path is **worthless**.

The HTML file upload actually sends the **content** of the file from the client to the server, usually along with only the file name. You just need to grab the content as an `InputStream` by [`FileItem#getInputStream()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getInputStream%28%29) or just to write it to disk directly by [`FileItem#write()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#write%28java.io.File%29). as per the [FileUpload User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html).

You can get the sole filename by [`FileItem#getName()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getName%28%29), but some webbrowsers however sends the full client side disk file system path, such as Internet Explorer and Opera. This is **wrong**. You need to trim off the path by `FilenameUtils#getName()` as per the [FileUpload FAQ](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE).

(by the way, all code in blue is clickable and points to the Javadocs, I strongly recommend you to learn reading/interpreting it as well, they namely provide all information you need).

Comment: Also, IMO: If a browser sends that information, it's somehow abusing the user's trust: Do I really want to disclose my username, or the way I organize my files (which is all in my paths)? For me, that's one more nail in the coffin for IE (and unfortunately, also Opera as I've just learned).

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get file path from client side due to browser's security
policy. You have to do it via a signed java applet or get it from your
servlet.

fileUpload.getFilename may or may not return full path. Depends on the browser

Comment: is there any way to do this ?